# How to maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have maintain/Save/Restore scroll position of listview  when returning to ListView. Here is my code line for maintain/Save/Restore scroll position of listview  when returning to ListView . This is for when i click on listView  item and comeback to listview  at that time maintain scroll position when return back to the page. But when i adding some new texttual item to the beginning of list view  from different page that time i want to display the listview from beginning of list view item.How to solve this issue.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        int index = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
       // Log.e(""," 111 index="+index);
        View view = listView.getChildAt(0);
        int top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();
       // Log.e("", "222 top=" + top);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("key1", index);
        editor.putInt("key2", top);
        editor.commit();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if( savedInstanceState != null )
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, savedInstanceState .getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        setContentView(R.layout.all_post);
}
```

Comment: check the size of ur list in onSaveInstanceState, if the size of ur list same as while leaving the activity then retain the same position else call notifyDatasetChanged on adapter object..

Comment: @Navin Shriyan : Thanks for the reply . Can you give me some code line please.

Comment: y u r saving that position in onSavedInstancestate?

Comment: i need ur flow to answer, where it will go when u click on the list item.? when u will come back to list view activity again?where and when ur list view get added with some more items?

Comment: @Navin Shriyan : Great . Thanks for the help . I solve my list view scroll position because of your guidance .   Thank you so much .

Comment: @Navin Shriyan : Great . Thanks for the help . I solve my list view scroll position issue because of your guidance . Thank you so much

Comment: Great!!:) glad to here:) could u tell me which part of my comment helped u, i will post it as answer and u can mark it as right so that everyone can get help from that...